# Pentaho Data Integration - Assure that one step will be run before another

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a transformation in Pentaho Data Integration that stores data in several tables from a database.

But this database has constraints, meaning I can't put things in a table before the related data is put in another table.

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, depends on concurrency luck.

So I need to assure that `Table Output 1` gets entirely run before `Table Output 2` starts.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a step named "Block this step until steps finish".

You place it before the step that needs to wait. And inside the block you define which steps are to be waited for.

---

Below, suppose, `Table Output 2` contains a foreign key to a field in table 1, but the rows you're going to reference in table 2 still don't exist in table 1. This means `Table Output 2` needs to wait until `Table Output` finishes.

Place the "block" connected before Table Output 2:

[image: Place the block]

Then enter the properties of the "block" step. Inside, add `Table Output` in the list (and any other steps you want to wait for):

[image: Tell it what to wait for]

Answer (score 1):

For that, you can use **job** instead of transformation. because in transformation all the steps run **parallelly**. so use a job in that add the first transformation in which **table output1** will be executed first and in second transformation **table output2** will be performed